# Fields added to SQL Backend lock the records in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

We have a database that is using a SQL Server backend with a MS Access and Filemaker frontend. It has been working fine. I added two fields to one of the tables today, one datetime field and one bit field.
When the table was updated in Access they can no longer edit a field in the records. A Write Conflict error comes up
"The record has been changed by another user since you started editing it. If you save the record, you will overwrite the changes the other user made. Copy the changes to the clipboard will let you look at the values the other user entered and then paste you changes back in if you decide to make chages.

The save Record option is grayed out.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: It could be so many things.  Did you make the new fields nullable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing Record issues in Access / SQL (Write Conflict)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993301/editing-record-issues-in-access-sql-write-conflict)

Answer (score 0):

Is the bit column nullable? MS Access can show those symptoms when dealing with a nullable bit column.

Comment: yes it was set nullable. I changed it to an interger and things work fine. So just changing it to not null would also work?