# SQL Server rows not editable for Access after Insert

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert, locked, ms-access-2000

I have this problem: I'm using a SQL Server 2008R2 backend and MS Access 2000 frontend where some tables are connected via ODBC.

Following Structure (Tables all on SQL-Server):

- Import (not connected to Access)
- Products (connected via ODBC to Access)
- Pricing (connected via ODBC to Access)

I want to fill the Pricing table automatically with some data from Products and Import. This is supposed to run as a SQL Agent job with a T-SQL script.
I want to insert the data from "Products" with following command:

```
INSERT INTO Pricing (Productnr, Manufacturernr)
    (SELECT Productnr, Manufacturernr 
     FROM Products 
     WHERE Valid = 1 
       AND Productnr NOT IN (SELECT Productnr FROM Pricing ));
```

Right after that the inserted rows are locked for Access, I can't change anything. If I execute sql queries with SQL Server Management Suite or if i start queries as SQL Agent jobs everything works fine.

Why are the rows locked in ms access after the query ran (even if it finished successfully)? and how can I unlock them or make it unlock itself right after the query/job ran?

Thanks

Comment: Do you run this query as Access query or as Pass-Through query? What do you mean by "via T-SQL"? What exactly is "I'm importing a table" (linking or actually importing)?

Comment: My fault here, i´ve got a csv import into another table (lets say "import") and i dont want this to be accessable by user via ms access. because of that and other reasons i want to have the table "pricing" which gets its data inserted by "products" and "import", both via sql agent jobs with t-sql scripts (job should run hourly). The "pricing" and "products" are accessable via ms access

Comment: I'm afraid you completely lost me here. Please edit your question and describe the workflow - which table exists where (Access or SQL Server) / is edited where.

Comment: edited the question, hope its easier to understand my problem

Comment: Yes, much better, thank you. Although I'm stumped, that's very weird behaviour. So after running the INSERT command in SQL Server, then you open the ODBC-linked table in Access, and only the new records are locked? The old ones are editable? Does Access show any message when trying to edit the new records?

Comment: Yeah it´s weird. Yes just the inserted records are locked, when i insert some with access i can edit them after the insert and i can insert some with access after the sql insert too... so the table is unlocked, but the inserted rows are still locked. The error message i get says, that the dataset has been changed by another user and if i save it, i would undo the changes of the other user. (and asks me for copying into clipboard). When i try to delete a row it says Microsoft Jet Databasemodule stopped it, because me and another user try to edit the same data

Comment: Oh... that's something completely different than "locked". I'll write an answer.

Comment: "not editable" doesn't really provide more information than "locked". -- Please provide as much details as possible for this strange behaviour. Does it happen when you start editing a record or when you try to save it? What is the exact error message? How / when it is resolved at the moment? e.g. when you close/open the table? or Access?

Comment: Okay, i can open the table in Access, i can view every record. I can edit them but when it tries to save it (e.g. when i click in another row) it tells me "Dieser Datensatz wurde seit Beginn der Bearbeitung von einem anderen Benutzer geändert. Wenn Sie den Datensatz speichern, werden Sie die Änderungen des anderen Benutzers überschreiben." Saving the row is not possible. If i try to delete a row it tells me: "Das Microsoft Jet-Datenbankmodul hat den Vorgang angehalten, da Sie und ein weiterer Benutzer gleichzeitig versuchen, dieselben Daten zu verändern."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution for my Problem now.

I had to add a timestamp row into the pricing table, so access could recognize the change.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993301/editing-record-issues-in-access-sql-write-conflict

Answer (score 0):

When SQL Server inserts new rows, those new rows are in fact **exclusively locked** to prevent other transactions from reading or manipulating them - that's by design, and it's a good thing! And it's something you cannot change - you cannot insert *without* those locks.

You can *unlock* them by **committing** the transaction that they're being inserted under - once they're committed to SQL Server, you can access them again normally.

Comment: I´ve tried it with:

BEGIN TRANSACTION;   
use ar
INSERT INTO Pricing (Productnr, Manufacturernr)
    (SELECT Productnr, Manufacturernr 
     FROM Products 
     WHERE Valid = 1 
       AND Productnr NOT IN (SELECT Productnr FROM Pricing ));
COMMIT TRANSACTION;

Still locked in access...

Comment: @Misc: well, after the `COMMIT`, the rows are _free_ and _unlocked_ again, as far as SQL Server is concerned (no more locks should exist on them at this point)

Comment: tried it, deleted all rows, table is accessible via ms access, run the insert including the commit, try editing rows in ms access, tells me its locked

Answer (score 0):

> The error message i get says, that the dataset has been changed by another user and if i save it, i would undo the changes of the other user. (and asks me for copying into clipboard).

This is different from "locked", and completely normal.

If you have a ODBC linked table (or form based on the table) open, and change data in the backend, Access doesn't know about the change.

You need to do a full requery (Shift+F9) in Access to reload the data, afterwards all records can be edited again.

Comment: unfortunately it was not the solution for my problem, i still can´t edit inserted rows

Answer (score 0):

Access loads the data into the front end when the table is first accessed. If something in the backend changes the data, you need Access to refresh it first, before you can edit it from the front end (or see the changes).

Do this by (in Access) by closing and reopening the table, or switching to the table and pressing shift-F9 as Andre suggested, or programmatically using a requery statement.  You must requery, not refresh, for it to release the locks and register the changes made in SQL.

Comment: requerying was not helping me, answered it already, i had to use a timestamp row in the table for synchronizing access and sql server