# Cannot edit one record on linked table write conflict

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

We have a linked table in our Access 2010 database, the backend is SQL Server 2012, via an ODBC connection. The table is indexed (unique, non clustered) on a single field, the record's identifier.

The issue is that the odd record throws a 'write conflict - record changed by another user' type error when it is edited through the Access front end, but can be edited directly in SQL. Other records are fine. It's not the same record each day.  The whole situation is a complete mystery to me so here are all the fact, maybe someone can make a coherent picture out of this.

The error message takes two different forms, depending how the edit is attempted.  The normal functioning of the front end does it by opening a DAO recordset with just the one record, doing a bunch of edits on different fields, then closing the recordset and setting all object variables back to nothing.  That produces first the "Write Conflict - This record has been changed by another user since you started editing it." error, with "Drop changes" or "Copy To Clipboard" as the options."  It is then followed up with error 3197 "The Microsoft Access database engine stopped the process because you and another user attempted to change the same data at the same time."

If I just open the table in Access and manually try to change the record, I get the write conflict version of the error only.  (Needless to say, I have confirmed that no other users are in the table at all, let alone the record.)

I can edit the row in SQL, and I can edit the row using a query in Access (via query design).

The data in the table is built each morning, and each day it seems to be a different record or two that is affected.  It has only gone on for a few weeks, in a setup that has been running fine for about 6 months with no changes that could account for this (at least, that I can think of).  The data build truncates the table and inserts all the records from scratch, and then rebuilds the index.

Here are some things I've tried:
Decompiling the database, compact and repair, relinking the table.
Linking the table into a brand new database that only has that one table in it.
Rebuilding the index.
Deleting the row and re-inserting it
Rebooting the SQL server (that was due to something else, but the problem still continued afterward.)
Opening the front end on a different computer.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the schema of the table to your question (e.g. a CREATE TABLE statement)? -- It sounds a bit like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43674267/sql-server-rows-not-editable-for-access-after-insert - a Rowversion (aka Timestamp) column may help.

Comment: It is a very wide table, too big to post usefully - what might you be looking for, so I can provide a useable extract?  The identifier is a unique 15 character text field; there are no funky data types, it's all just varchar or different sizes of integer and decimals. It's not really all that similar to that question, in that this isn't about something in the backend changing data, all the data changes are in the front end. Refreshing/requerying hasn't resolved anything.

Comment: I'll look into rowversion again, thank you.  Though I still can't understand why it would only apply on some records and not others, and be sustained through a server reboot!

Comment: Some Decimal type sizes may be problematic, perhaps only with specific values. Or 64-bit Bigint, if you use these. Just put the CREATE TABLE into a code block, so it will be scrollable.

Comment: Usually this is caused by rounding errors. Access checks the if values in the row have changed and when Server and Access use different rounding strategies, it thinks the data has changed. That's why you need a primary key and a timestamp, so Access checks if timestamp changed not the field values.